# jquery datatable object from settings

Tags: javascript, datatables

I'm using the jQuery DataTables plugin. Within its `initComplete` callback (which has settings as parameter available) I'm trying to make a jQuery table object.

With the following command (from [`DataTables.Settings`](https://datatables.net/reference/type/DataTables.Settings))

```
var api = new $.fn.dataTable.Api( settings );
```

it's easily possible to create a (datatables) table object? All attempts to convert it to a jQuery object failed. The jQuery object is needed, since I need it's `find` method later on.

Is there a way to get a jQuery object form the settings directly. Or if not, can the API be converted to a jQuery one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`table().node()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/table%28%29.node%28%29) API method.

```js
var api = new $.fn.dataTable.Api( settings );
$(api.table().node()).addClass('highlight');
```